# SpringBoot JPA Update multiple rows using Query

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a JPA repository defined like

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface SampleRepository
    extends CrudRepository<Sample, String> {

  @Modifying
  @Query("update Sample t "
      + "where t.id in (:ids)")
  public int updateByIds(@Param("ids") List<String> id);
```

Here in clause in Query is not working. Does on clause in Query not supported in JPA?

Comment: You're not setting any value in t. So this query doesn't make sense. When asking about an error, always post the exact and complete error.